# Using Regex in PHP I convert URLs and EMails to HTML links

Tags: php, regex

I've searched wide and far on here and I can't find anything that matches my specific need.

I need to parse a block of text with regex in PHP and do two things.

1. Convert URLs to HTML links
2. Convert EMails to `mailto:` HTML links

I have them working seperatly but the problem is the URL transformer will attempt to link domains off email address. And if I go the other way first, the EMail links' href attribute will get re-linked causing broken HTML.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
public function getParsedBodyAttribute()
{
    $string = $this->body;

    $string = preg_replace('/(\S+@\S+\.\S+)/', '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>', $string);

    return preg_replace('(?!(?!.*?<a)[^<]*<\/a>)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]', '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $string);
}
```

Comment: Provide examples of what you are working with.

Comment: I need http://www.google.com https://google.com google.com someone@somewhere.com to be linked. Hopefully this is what you meant by examples.

Comment: So I guess ideally first it'd link all the emails, and then go thru and look for URLs that are not in <a> blocks already.

Comment: You haven't any capturing groups in the url regex, you can't use `$2://$4` in the replacement part.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you out.

```js
<?php
//REGEX &copy; https://github.com/virdwait/virdwaitJs
$str = "http://www.google.com , works in ftp://ftp.google.com , then in www.twitter.com , now google.com  and again it is https://www.facebook.com/ and then changed to  :  sagarvd01@gmail.com ";
$str=preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}((\!|\#|\$|\%|\&|\'|\*|\+|\-|\/|\=|\?|\^|\_|\`|\{|\||\}|\~|\!|\#|\$|\%|\&|\'|\*|\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,6}){0,1}){1}/','<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>',$str);
$str=preg_replace('/((((https:\/\/|http:\/\/|ftp:\/\/){0,1}(www.|ftp.){1})|\s[^www\.]){1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}){0,1}(\/){0,1}){1}/','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$str);

echo $str;

//return $str
?>
```

See a demo [Here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gjzg-efrb)

Comment: That works well, but I need all something.com to also work. It seems like yours only works on URLs with `http://`

Comment: You've come upon my need to post on Stack Overflow haha

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean?

Comment: The project I'm working on needs to be able to match `google.com` that's why I came here lol

Comment: Do you really think that your regexes are better than OP? They are unreadable.

Comment: @Toto The regex for email I shared here is developed by myself for one of my project. The rules matches the universal standard for email. It is somewhat difficult to read for me also. But it is the original email format.

Comment: You don't need to escape all theses characters, you don't need to capture all these groups. I suggest you a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info for regex tutorial then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples for examples of valid and invalid addresses, and http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db for existing TLDs.

Comment: Keep in mind if the email already wrapped in a link this will double link it causing invalid HTML